# What does the tilde (~) mean in my composer.json file?

Tags: symfony, syntax, composer-php

I have this line in my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    ...
},
```

What does the tilde `~` in  `~2.0@dev` exactly mean? Is that a placeholder and shall always fetch the subversions like `1.2.0`, `2.2.0`, `3.2.0` and so on? Doesn't make sense (and would be done by the `*` wildcard).

The [composer.json documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) doesn't tell anything about the tilde.

I am asking because I just read about a [security issue in the Symfony blog](http://symfony.com/blog/category/security-advisories) and they recommend to upgrade to version 1.3.3. But figuring out the FOSUserBundle's version isn't that easy (I couldn't find a file that contains the version).

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Tilde means *next significant release*. In your case, it is equivalent to `>= 2.0, < 3.0`.

The full explanation is at [Tilde Version Range docs page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-):

> The `~` operator is best explained by example: `~1.2` is equivalent to `>=1.2 <2.0.0`, while `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0`.
>
> Another way of looking at it is that using `~` specifies a minimum
>   version, but allows the last digit specified to go up.

Seldeak's below comment is a simple sum up explanation of the Composer documentation.

Comment: A simple rule-of-thumb way I like to put it is that the ~ allows the last digit to go up. e.g. `~2.2` means 2.2 and any 2.x where x is 2 or above. `~2.1.3` on the is also any 2.1.x where x is 3 or above.

Comment: How is `~2.0` different to `2.*`? Is it only useful if the last digit isn't 0?

Comment: ~2.0 and 2.* are the same BUT ~2.3 and 2.* are different because ~2.3 does not allow versions below 2.3 whereas 2.* allows 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, etc

Answer (score 4):

`Tilde` operator is useful for the projects that version their libraries using `semantic versioning` scheme.

`Semantic versioning` is more of a guideline that evaluates to the `next significant release`.

For Composer, this operator means to allow minor releases (that can include patches) without allowing a major version (that may not be backward compatible) while *installing* and *updating*.

For example: `~4.1` will allow project versions `>=4.1` but `<5.0`.

Credits: http://dwellupper.io/post/37/using-tilde-range-operator-to-resolve-dependency-version-in-composer-php

Answer (score 2):

The tilde `~` is one of [many constraints that can be used to handle versions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-).

[Next Significant Release Operators (~, ^)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md):

> The `~` operator is best explained by example: `~1.2` is equivalent to `>=1.2 <2.0.0`, while `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0`

> The `^` operator behaves very similarly, but it sticks closer to
> semantic versioning, and will always allow non-breaking updates. For
> example `^1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0` as none of the releases
> until 2.0 should break backwards compatibility. For pre-1.0 versions
> it also acts with safety in mind and treats `^0.3` as `>=0.3.0 <0.4.0`

[Hyphenated Version Range (-)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#hyphenated-version-range-)

> Inclusive set of versions. Partial versions on the right include are
> completed with a wildcard. For example `1.0 - 2.0` is equivalent to
> `>=1.0.0 <2.1` as the `2.0` becomes `2.0.*`. On the other hand `1.0.0 - 2.1.0` is equivalent to `>=1.0.0 <=2.1.0`

[Wildcard Version Range (.*)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#wildcard-version-range-)

> You can specify a pattern with a * wildcard. `1.0.*` is the equivalent
> of `>=1.0 <1.1`

[Simple  Version Range (>, >=, <, <=, !=)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#version-range)

> By using comparison operators you can specify ranges of valid
> versions. Valid operators are >, >=, <, <=, !=.
>
> You can define multiple ranges. Ranges separated by a space ( ) or
> comma (`,`) will be treated as a logical AND. A double pipe (`||`) will be
> treated as a logical OR. AND has higher precedence than OR.

And finally [Exact Version Constraint](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#exact-version-constraint)

> You can specify the exact version of a package
> Example: `1.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

The tilde **`~` in  `~2.0@dev`** exactly mean to go up for immediate version :

*For Example :*

*If we have `~2.0@dev` it goes to up immediate next version  `=> ~2.x@dev`*