# what is the difference of ~5.0 to "5.1.*"

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravelcollective

In laravel compposer i have this

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
    },
```

then I found in the doucumentation [laravelcollective/html](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#text)to add this in composer

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
```

what is the difference if we use ~ than * ?
or how do I read this  `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"`
and this  `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the tilde (~) mean in my composer.json file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979729/what-does-the-tilde-mean-in-my-composer-json-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking a look at the [composer documentation for ~](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde):

> ... using ~ specifies a minimum version, but allows the last digit specified to go up.

So `~5.0` would match `5.0`, `5.1`, `5.2`, (including sub-versions like `5.0.3`) etc. where as `5.1.*` would match only versions that start with `5.1`, but without caring about the third version identifier.

With `~`, you could specify something like: `~5.1.3` and you would be able to get versions `5.1.3`, `5.1.4`, etc., but not versions `5.1.2` or `5.2.0`.